# How does one paste code into an Office Communicator conversation

Tags: windows, office-communicator-2007, emoticons

Whenever you paste code into Office Communicator, it decides to convert half of your code into emoticons.  I'd like to prevent this from happening, so the other side can read the code, and copy it as well.

There is an option to turn off showing emoticons in your conversation window, but I don't think this affects the messages you send.

Comment: Indeed, that setting is just for the emoticon strings you receive. You may have to tell the person you're conversing with to turn off the emoticons before you send your code.

Answer (score 4):

If the code isn't too sensitive you could use a service like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and send the URL via IM instead.

Comment: It's also worth noting that many (not sure about OC) IM clients will yield the original text when cutting and pasting out messages.  The recipient should try copying your message into notepad or an IDE and see what they get.

Comment: that doesn't help with OC.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Office Communicator, but if this a matter of the formatting of the text, then one can paste the pure text without formatting by using the free product [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/).

If it is not a matter of formatting, the free utility [sanvient](http://www.deepskyblue.net/software/sanvient/en/) can paste text while replacing a regular expression. I do not know this product, but if you define the emoticons via a regular expression, you may be able to edit them out when pasting via this utility.

[HovText](http://www.hovklan.com/hovtext/) is another simpler utility that can paste while filtering out text with regular expressions.

Comment: It's not a matter of rich text. The parentheses in the code enable emoticons. The best solution would be to have an on-site pastebin server.