# How to Disable Emoticons in Microsoft Office Communicator

Tags: emoticons, ms-office-communicator

Communicator is the preferred way of dialog between developers in the organization I work in. The program, however, has some screwed up default settings: For instance, when you paste code into a conversation, there are often changes so that code is replaced with emoticons.

This is highly annoying, and i want to turn off emoticons/smileys completely.

Note there is a similar question: [How does one paste code into an Office Communicator conversation](https://superuser.com/questions/146444/how-does-one-paste-code-into-an-office-communicator-conversation). Where answers suggest not to use Communicator. But unlike that, I do not accept suggestions not to use Communicator.

So please, here, provide details on how I turn off my communicator to not show emoticons.

Comment: This link would be useful for you http://www.scottfeltmann.com/index.php/tag/office-communicator/

Comment: Thanks for posting the link. There is a setting DisableEmoticons mentioned in the link, but no explanation on how to use it. Is there a property file i can modify before startup? or is it an administrator-only thing. (the link mentions something about an administrator)

Comment: It's in the Lync Management Shell, so typically only an admin would have access.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Communicator's `Tools->Options` menu, on the "`General`" tab, there is a checkbox called "`Show emoticons in instant messages`".

[image]

Deselecting this will cause emoticons to not appear in your Communicator. Of course you will still need your colleagues to do the same, if they don't want code "corrupted" in their instances of Communicator.

Comment: Aah. THIS was what i was looking for. Unchecking `Show emoticons in instant messages` does exactly what i asked for

Answer (score 3):

There is a policy called "DisableEmoticons." I believe you have to download [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21652).

Comment: I will not accept this answer. Since i am not an administrator. And i will not solve this for everyone in my company. It will simply not be accepted by it department. The solution I am looking for has to be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Above "Show Emoticons.." in settings used to reset after next login for me.
I found a permanent solution.. open registry (regedit), search for "ShowEmoticons" modify value data of all communicator related values to 0. You're done!

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Office Communicator 2005 the option to disable emoticons is actually under the Instant Messages tab:

[image]