# How can I disable the smiley faces Lync generates?

Tags: lync, lync-2013

In a conversation recently I tried to paste a code sample into a Lync window to send to a colleague. Something like:

`$env:PATH += ";C:\Your\Path\Here"`

Unfortunately, Lync interpreted `:P` as a "sticking one's tongue out" smiley face, and produced a message like this:

[image: Lync message example]

Is there anything I can do to prevent Lync from turning this into a smiley face?

Comment: There's a relevant thread [on doing exactly this for *communicator*](http://superuser.com/questions/347347/how-to-disable-emoticons-in-microsoft-office-communicator), but I don't think those options exist with Lync.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

1. Click on the Settings gear icon
2. Hover over Tools
3. Click on Options
4. Click on the General tab
5. Uncheck "Show emoticons in instant messages"

As you, rightly mentioned in your comment, you will have to do the same on your co-worker's PC as well because this only affects settings of Lync running on your machine.

[image: Lync Options]

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this only affects local display, not people viewing the message. But tis better than nothing.

Comment: In my version, it is under Tools/Options/IM/"Show emoticons in messages"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no escape character for disabling emoticons in Lync. You could try disabling them via [client policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398300.aspx) if you have access to do so.

Comment: Is there a way to disable only *some* smileys, especially via client policy?